# Is there a glossary of camera metadata terms?

Tags: metadata

I'm trying to learn to interpret my camera's metadata (Exif) tags (if "tags" is the right word) as they appear in Adobe Bridge. I'm seeing some terms I don't understand and I was wondering if there was such a thing as a glossary for this. For example, there's Exposure, Exposure Mode, Exposure Program, Exposure Index, Exposure Bias Value. I can figure out *some* of them by turning them on and off and seeing if they're connected any terms I recognize, like "aperture priority" or "f11" ... but it would be nice if I could look them all up somewhere, preferably online. Does such a resource exist? I've tried online searches but I may not be using the best keywords. I've looked in my camera's (Nikon D5200) manual and I'm not seeing it there. Thanks for any clues!

Answer (score 7):

There is some standard EXIF data, but there is also a lot that is vendor specific as well.  The EXIF standard would be the best place to look for standard values and their meanings.  Other values are added by vendors.

[Exif standard 2.3](http://www.cipa.jp/english/hyoujunka/kikaku/pdf/DC-008-2010_E.pdf)  See around page 27 or so for a pretty decent glossary of the official standard tags.

[Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/metadata.html) seems to have a pretty good list that includes some of the vendor specific ones as well.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the EXIF standard, the [IPTC photo metadata](http://www.iptc.org/cms/site/index.html?channel=CH0099) standard contains lots of definition of field purpose and acceptable values. There's a lot of crossover between EXIF and IPTC field names and purposes, though the IPTC version of the field is typically a little better defined. That said, they are both very open-ended and you'll find a good deal of variety in the content and formatting of the field data.